# Chromecast Audio/PulseAudio-DLNA Lag

Tags: kubuntu, pulseaudio, dlna, audio-sync, chromecast

I successfully connected a Chromecast audio unit using Pulseaudio-DLNA to my Dell Inspiron 13 7348 running Kubuntu 16.04. However, there is always a 2-5 second lag from when I press to play a sound to the sound coming out of the speakers. Is there any way to fix this problem?

Comment: If you play a long clip, (like playing a YouTube video) does it just delay in the beginning, or does it cut out for a few seconds in the middle of it? Because I'm thinking that buffering is to blame here. That way, if the Chromecast gets a few corrupted packets from the WLAN, the music is cached for  a second or two while the packets are resent.

Comment: @AndroidDev It only delays in the beginning

Comment: Well, then my guess is as I said above. I think it's the Chromecast's doing, not Pulseaudio

Comment: @AndroidDev What are the steps I need to take to eliminate this problem?

Comment: I don't think you can do anything about it. I suggest you contact Google to find out if it does in fact buffer a few seconds of audio

Comment: I don't think it is the Chromecast Audio device, because the delay only occurs in `pulseaudio-dlna`.  I have an Android device that casts the sound immediately.  And I've cast from a Mac too.  I've tried using different `pulseaudio-dlna` preferences (e.g., setting it to use wav instead of mp3), but the delay remains.   And for me, the delay gets worse over time.  When I first start casting, the sound is 1-2 seconds delay.  But after an hour of listening to music, it increases to around 30 seconds.

Comment: @AndroidDev Its a fault with Pulse Audio; I cast audio through Google Cast on my chrome browser on the exact same laptop and there was no delay